# The item cannot be restored from trash

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, delete, restore, trash

I don't know why all my files and folders in home location starts appearing on desktop so,I deleted all the files and folders on desktop as i thought that they are temporary after the deletion of those files all the original files also moved to trash.
When i tried to restore all the files and folders from the trash i found an annoying message as shown in the figure.[image]

Please help me to solve this issue all my files and project work which are very important for me went into this trash.Another thing was all the app data was also went missing. [image]
I am not able to recover all these files.

Answer (score 0):

First what happened. Probably for some reason, (could have been because of some moving or renaming folders) your special folder "Desktop" was set to be your home folder. As a result, all your folders of Home also appear on your desktop.

Of course, it was not the best reaction to delete the files on your desktop if you recognized these to be the ones of your home folder. Nevertheless, they normally should be recoverable through the trash. So apparently something went wrong there as well.

With the file manager, you can look directly into the trash. Try *copying* missing files out of that trash, preferably to an attached external disk, so you can save the most recent versions of your files.

Once you recovered the maximum of files, it is preferred to check the consistency of the file system. Normally, that should be done automatically during the next boot.

Then restore your files and folders. The most secure way would be to copy all files back from your backup, then replace with newer versions of files that you rescued from the Trash (after you verified that these files are not corrupt).